# Is is possible to use ADO.net to wrap an existing ODBC connection?

Tags: ado.net, odbc, wrapper

We have an existing ODBC connection (for example, a legacy product which is already connected with database and also can return a ODBC connection handle), and we want to wrapper this connection handle through ADO.net. Then our secondary development user can use this ADO.net wrapper library to access the database.

How would one go about doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. ADO.NET has an ODBC provider and in fact is the preferred way to use ADO.NET in a database neutral manner since OleDb didn't catch on like MS hoped.

Ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.odbc.aspx

Comment: Could you give more details? how to leverage the existing connection handle? it seems that ADO.net's odbc constructors only has the following two: OdbcConnection() and OdbcConnection(String)  the second one needs a connection string to trigger a new connection, instead of taking use of existing odbc connection. How to construct a ADO.net by an existing connection?

Comment: Are you asking how to create the connection string? http://www.connectionstrings.com/dsn#net-framework-data-provider-for-odbc  Or are you asking how to re-use an existing connection? To reuse an existing connection, .Close() all commands and readers. Then re-use the connection while it is still in scope and while you haven't called .Close() or .Dispose() on it yet.

Comment: Both No, what I'm asking is that we already have a interface, e.g., GetODBCConnectionHandle, which is able to returned an existing connected odbc handle from another C++/C library. However, I don't want to my target caller to use ODBC C++ programming, and also we don't want to my target caller to provide the connection string(even I don't want them to know the db/password and something else), I just want to wrapper this returned connection in ADO.net class/interface/object whatever. The caller just use the ADO.net interface to execute command(no need to connect first). Is it possible?

Comment: Sure it's possible, you'd be creating something that derives from all the System.Data.Common classes, such as DbCommand, DbConnection, etc, and the implementation of those derived classes would call your pre-existing code. It sounds like your  GetODBCConnectionHandle wrapped in ADO.NET provider classes does what System.Data.Odbc does already.  Are you trying to use some feature of native ODBC that isn't surfaced by System.Data.Odbc?